# Copy text from terminal and paste to Vim while preserving text color

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Is there a way to copy colored text from terminal and paste it as colored into vim?

I am on `MacOS`, using `iTerm2 Build 3.4.4beta3`, and the following `Vim` version:

```
% vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jan 19 2021 18:24:53)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-2375
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-): ...
```

Thanks

Comment: That would be like pasting colored text into Notepad.  Vim supports syntax highlighting, but I don't think Vim is aware of arbitrary ANSI text colors from the terminal.

Comment: You can't copy paste it, but you can save it to a file and then load that with Vim. If you use tmux then you can save the screen (or entire scrollback) to a file. Or you can of course pipe the output from a command to Vim.